# Restart then() block when catch is returned an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, instagram

I want to restart my code when catch function is returned an error.

```
let ig = require('instagram-scraping')


module.exports.instagram = async (req, res) => {
ig.scrapeTag('postthisonmypersonalblogtoo').then(async result => {
    let myPostCodes = [];

    result.medias.forEach(content => {
        if(content.owner_id == '10601516006'){
            myPostCodes.push(content.shortcode);
        }
    })

    await res.render('instagram', {
        myPosts : myPostCodes
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    // if(err){ 
          //ig.scrapeTag('postthisonmypersonalblogtoo').then(async result => { ... } //do same things as above
     }
})
```

}

The reason that i wanted to do this: sometimes ig.scrapeTag method find my posts but sometimes cant find anything and return me that;

```
Error: Error scraping tag page "postthisonmypersonalblogtoo"
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Byte\Desktop\BLOG\node_modules\instagram-scraping\index.js:114:24)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Byte\Desktop\BLOG\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
```

So when i take this error i want to reset ig.scrapeTag to research my posts on instagram again

(By the way sorry for my bad English and if you guys have a advice for another instagram api let me know (api can be official or unofficial doesn't matter)

Comment: Just recursively call the `module.exports.instagram` function again (with a recursion depth limit, though)

Comment: I give a response in InstagramRoute.js like that -> 

router.get('/', InstagramController.instagram);

How can i know that when InstagramController.instagram return me an error?

Answer (score 2):

I would move scrape functionality into separate function and introduce retry counter to keep track of number of retries. Also not sure why you mix and match `then/catch` with `async/await`. I think it is more readable and consistent to use `async/await` everywhere. Something like this:

```js
let ig = require('instagram-scraping')

const MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 2;

async function scrapeInstagram() {  
  let retryCount = 0;
  const scrapeTag = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await ig.scrapeTag('postthisonmypersonalblogtoo');
      return result;
    }
    catch(e) {
       if (retryCount < MAX_RETRY_COUNT) {
          retryCount++;
          scrapeTag();
       } else {
          throw e;
       }
    }
  }

  const result = await scrapeTag();
  let myPostCodes = [];

  result.medias.forEach(content => {
        if(content.owner_id == '10601516006'){
            myPostCodes.push(content.shortcode);
        }
    });
   return myPostCodes;
}

module.exports.instagram = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const myPostCodes = await scrapeInstagram();
    await res.render('instagram', {
        myPosts : myPostCodes
    }); 
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send("Could not load from Instagram")
  }
}
```

Comment: Notice that in the case of an error in the `instagram` method, you should do something like `res.status(500).send("Could not load from Instagram")` in addition to logging the error.

Comment: This code is actually good but sometimes its returning me that

Cannot read property 'medias' of undefined

This is because of the ig.scrapeTag couldn't get anything from the tag... I feel like im stupid from this time...

Comment: @Mad I guess you should add some checking on the result of scrapeTag, I have no idea what can be returned from it

Comment: Code is really make sense but why is not working? I set MAX_RETRY_COUNT  as 50 but it still returning me that error -> 'medias' of undefined.

Comment: It's returning us this error because of its couldn't get posts from my tag.

Comment: It's returned me medias are undefined but medias is exist... Whaat? I really couldn't understand it.

Comment: You could add console.log after `ig.scrapeTag` and check what is returned.

Comment: Where did you add console.log, hard to say what is wrong by that info